Snowflake String Match



Column A




cat, dog, horse


monkey, donkey


cat, tree



I need a way to return me the rows which matches the string 'cat|ball|tree'. Here my expected output is TRUE for first and third row and false for second row as there is cat matching for the first row and cat and tree matching for the third row. And no match for second row.
SELECT CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE ('cat, dog, horse', 'cat|ball|tree') THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS match_found;
I tried using REGEXP_LIKE but it returns FALSE.
Also tried REGEXP only
SELECT 'cat, dog, horse' REGEXP 'cat|ball|tree'.
Edit:
I found this approach.
SELECT  CASE  WHEN ARRAY_SIZE(ARRAY_INTERSECTION(SPLIT('cat,horse',','), SPLIT('mouse|horse','|'))) > 0 THEN TRUE  ELSE FALSE  END AS stringmatched;
Is there any better way?

Don't store data as comma separated items, it will only cause you lots of problems.

@jarlh I need to put it this way this is the requirement. However I can change the delimiter.

It's not the comma that is the problem. A normalized database is so much easier to handle.

REGEXP usage notes states

The function implicitly anchors a pattern at both ends (i.e. '' automatically becomes '^$', and 'ABC' automatically becomes '^ABC$').

This means that your pattern is searching for an exact match of cat, ball, or tree. Since you have more in the array than just the search strings, you need the following query:
select * from t
where column1 regexp '.*cat.*|.*ball.*|.*tree.*';

